# import com.parse.ParseUser "cannot be resolved"

Tags: android, parse-platform

This problem is an issue with android studio and Parse.com

So I am learning from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eo-OHZuGPLE) and I ran across an issue after my computer crashed from a crazy error when I ran the app in the emulator. After it restarted it seemed to be patching some files and now a bunch of calls to Parse don't seem to be working.

I am working in Android Studio

All of these calls that are not recognized come from ParseUser so it seems that ParseUser files just seemed to stop existing. How to I repair it so it recognizes ParseUser again? I tried to take out Parse-1.jar and input a new one in the libs and that didn't seem to fix it. I also tried cleaning, syncing, and building several times and it didn't change anything.

I don't think showing any code will really help clarify my problem since its just a problem with the calling something from Parse but if you think it will help I can post a screenshot of my code. The code below is all that I think will be relevant to this problem.

Here is all of the code of my Lorem class:

```
package com.commonsware.lorem;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;


public class Lorem extends ActionBarActivity {

    //private static final String="POST";
    ListView listView;
    int[] pic_thumbnail_resource = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,};
    String[] post_ratings;
    String[] post_titles;
    PostAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Parse

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "wHN7DSZyAzVXT5fg5PCQUVBwOWasUExbeuePvQvL", "SsvjuJ7e97FsRkI12XI7olg8RilgSoFSw5waIOXM");
        //ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        //testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        //testObject.saveInBackground();

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            // do stuff with the user


        } else {
            // show the signup or login screen
            Intent takeUsertoLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(takeUsertoLogin);
        }

        // End Parse

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lorem);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        post_ratings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.post_ratings);
        post_titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.post_titles);

        //populateListView();
        registerClickCallback();

        int i = 0;
        adapter = new PostAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for(String titles: post_titles)
        {
            PostDataProvider dataProvider = new PostDataProvider(pic_thumbnail_resource[i], titles, post_ratings[i]);
            adapter.add(dataProvider);
            i++;
        }
    }


    private void registerClickCallback(){
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id){
                TextView textView = (TextView) viewClicked;
                String message = "You clicked # " + position + ",which is string: " + textView.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Lorem.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

/*
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(String requestCode, String resultCode, Intent data){

        if (requestCode == "POST")
        {
            myItems.add
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
*/

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_lorem, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.post:
                aboutItemPost();
                break;
            case R.id.location:
                aboutItemLocation();
                break;
            case R.id.topic:
                aboutItemTopic();
                break;
            case R.id.sort:
                aboutItemSort();
                break;
            case R.id.login:
                aboutItemLogin();
            case R.id.Register:
                aboutItemRegister();
            case R.id.Logout:
                aboutItemLogout();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void aboutItemPost(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    private void aboutItemLocation(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    private void aboutItemTopic(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TopicActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }

    private void aboutItemSort(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Sort")
                .setMessage("This is where the user will sort what they want to see")
                .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).show();

    }

    private void aboutItemLogin(){
        Intent takeUsertoLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(takeUsertoLogin);
    }

    private void aboutItemRegister(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    private void aboutItemLogout() {
        // log the user out
        ParseUser.logOut();

        // take the user back to log in screen
        Intent takeUsertoLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(takeUsertoLogin);

    }

}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Sync with gradle again?  What does your build.gradle look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the Parse jar files under app/libs

In your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar') }
```